# Python subprocess.Popen() and stdout file object association

Tags: python, subprocess

I wonder the association between **subprocess.Popen()** object and **stdout** and how it converts **Popen** instance into a file object.

```
type(subprocess.Popen)  # <type 'type'>

subprocess.Popen(":", shell=True).__class__  # <class 'subprocess.Popen'>

type(subprocess.Popen(":", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout)  # <type 'file'>
```

But,

`dir(subprocess.Popen)` does not have **stdout** as its member

Comment: It's an attribute
try `help(subprocess.Popen)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` is an attribute in class [`Popen`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4173772031747a9b249be4100b4aa9eda805ea23/Lib/subprocess.py#L660) which is defined as below
[`self.stdout = None`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4173772031747a9b249be4100b4aa9eda805ea23/Lib/subprocess.py#L749)